# Is there any way to change Boot Volume for the Instance

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have a backup for Boot Volume. I can create new Boot Volume from it and attach to a new instance.

But I need to save the existing one with all settings. Is it possible to just replace one Boot Volume to another?

Comment: What do you mean by the settings? 

All the information like boot/start-up scripts and OS image will be stored in the boot volume. When you create a new instance with that boot volume all the files will be there too. What else do you want to save?

Comment: I mean OCI instance settings: name, network, availability domain, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No.

There is no direct way to replace the boot volume of an instance. You have to first terminate the instance. So that you can use the boot volume again.

Then you have to create a new instance with same or different settings(as per your need). While creating the instance in the image selection field, there is a tab called `boot volumes` at which you can select the existing boot volume.

Comment: Is there any plans to implement that?

Comment: I don't know, you have to contact Oracle support.

Comment: sad!!!!! that created a lot of difficulties for me ! what are they doing , even do a good work or let people do it. They seem to be sleeping, no modification in the features (not mentioning thw quota calculation bug for free tier users) ...